# How to use semaphore to lock table?

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions, semaphore

I would like to lock an MDB table from reads while a transaction executes.  I would use `dbDenyRead` but apparently this is unreliable and doesn't always the lock the table:

http://www.office-archive.com/32-ms-access/c2bd1a2553e79c60.htm

How can I use a semaphore solution to achieve a virtual lock on a table?

If I store the semaphore in another table with a row holding the table name and a process/workstation ID which will be cleared at the end of the transaction, how can I prevent the following sequence?

> 1. Process A queries semaphore table and finds it blank.
> 2. Process B queries semaphore table and finds it blank.
> 3. Process A updates semaphore table with Process A ID.
> 4. Process B updates semaphore table with Process B ID.
> 5. Both Process A and B perform transaction (not what I want).

Please no answers that include the use of the `IF` SQL statement because my version of JET-SQL can't use that.

Comment: How do you plan to deal with "proc A obtains lock, proc A starts working in protected table, proc A crashes"?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: if proc A crashes then its transaction won't be committed and its locks will be released, won't they?

Comment: I'm not sure - you seem to be working with fairly broken technology if you can't get many atomicity guarantees from the system, as you seem to be indicating.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I see your point now: how will the semaphore be cleared if there is a crash? Do I need to a have an expiry for the semaphore, say like 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will address *all* of your issues. But create a table with a Primary Key that isn't auto-generated. If possible, also declare the same column with some kind of check/rule that enforces that the column may only contain one possible value.

You now have a table that can contain 0 or 1 rows. To obtain the "semaphore", insert a row into the table, with the single fixed PK value. If this insert succeeds, you own the semaphore. If the insert fails due to a primary key violation, then you didn't obtain the semaphore. The key is to *not* perform a preliminary check first - just attempt the insert.

If your tech is so broken that it can't guarantee that the PK constraint will be maintained, then you seriously need to consider changing technology.

If you *fail* to insert the row, then you can start regularly polling this table - at whatever intervals seem appropriate.

---

The other alternative is to have the table have an autonumber PK column - when you want to obtain the semaphore, insert a row into the table. Then, query the table to locate the row with the lowest PK column value. If that row is *your* row, then you now own the semaphore. You still have to poll, but you effectively have a "reservation" recorded in this table.

As with the previous case, once you have completed your semaphore protected work, you delete your row from the table. This second approach should be "fairer" (in that each process gains access in strict order of requests), but may look be messier in practice. It does rely on *all* processes staying "live".

Comment: The PK constraint solution looks like the best bet. What about the crash scenario?