# How to connect to an MS Access database on the LAN using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, networking

I am developing the application using VB.Net and I have to use an MS Access database which is in the another system connected to the LAN. How can I connect to it?

Comment: and the question is....??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this piece of code you should be able to connect to an Access database and fill a `DataAdapter` with the content of a table.

```
    Dim con As New OledbConnection("Provider=microsoft.Jet.oledb.4.0;DataSource=RemoteServerName\Path\mydatabase.mdb;")

    Dim cmd As New OledbCommand

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table"
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, Table)
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Thank you sir, in this can i check whether the host is connected or not. that mean i have to show error message when the host is not exist.

Comment: Answer edited as per requested. Using `Try...Catch` you'll try to open the connection. If it fails, a `MessageBox` will appear showing the problem (database not found, max. number of connections reached..or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

If its a MS Access database,  the only way you can share it is to put it in a shared folder and configure the application to use the database from the shared folder.  However, please be advised that MSAccess lets only a limited number of users to access at the same time.

Comment: how can i improve the number of users

Comment: follow link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694921/ms-access-mdb-concurrency