# C# save record is not redirecting to correct MS Access Database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I am building a VSTO Excel Add-in in C#. This Add-In will save records to an individual MS Access database. Since Access does not support multiple users updating the same database, I had to create one access per user. The DBs are located in a SharePoint folder, which is already synced to the user desktop so I can use a similar file path for all databases, here is how I get the db file path:

```
string FilesPath1 = "C:/Users/" + loggedUser + "/Company Name/App Folder/DB/";
```

Where loggedUser is declared as follows:

```
public static string loggedUser = Environment.UserName.ToUpper()
```

So when the Add-In runs, will get the user name logged (AALV in my case). Here is the complete code for the save request function.

```
public static void SaveIndividualRequest(string idRequestUpdate,
                                                 string requestType,
                                                 string requestedBy,
                                                 string requestedTo,
                                                 string deadline
                                                 )
        {

            // instance for date
            DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            try
            {
                string FilesPath1 = "C:/Users/" + loggedUser + "/Company Name/App Folder/DB/";
                string IndividualRequestsPath1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilesPath1 + loggedUser + ".mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;";
                OleDbConnection connIndividualReq1 = new OleDbConnection(IndividualRequestsPath1);

                connIndividualReq1.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO [Requests] ([Request ID], [Request type], [Requested by], [Requested to], [Requested on], [Deadline], [Status]) VALUES " +
                    $"('{idRequestUpdate}', '{requestType}', '{requestedBy}', '{requestedTo}', '{today}', '{deadline}', 'Pending');";
                cmd.Connection = connIndividualReq1;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //inform user
                MessageBox.Show("Record has been saved and emal will be sent");

                connIndividualReq1.Close();
                cmd.Cancel();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); connIndividualReq.Close(); cmd.Cancel(); }
        }
```

The line: `string IndividualRequestsPath1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilesPath1 + loggedUser + ".mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;";` adds the `loggedUser` at the end of the string to get the individual access database (all dbs are named as the user name of all users).

This function works perfectly when I run it in my laptop, no only in debug, but once I publish and install the Add-In. However, when it runs in other user´s laptop there is an error, that states the DB is not found, but the Add-In is looking for my initials instead of the logged user: [Error from user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDqZq.png)

I also checked what the `Enviroment.UserName()` stores when other user runs it and place it in a form, indeed it is showing the correct user.

I hope any of you guys can help me with ideas.

Comment: Try from cmd.exe >SET to verify the environmental variable is set correctly.

Comment: Instead of storing the Environment.Username in a variable use it directly inside the _SaveIndividualRequest_ function. There is no advantage in storing it in a static variable that could be changed somewhere before code reaching your method

Comment: Side note. While it is a bit harder to hack Access with Sql Injection  your code is highly unsafe and prone to crash if some of those variables contains a single quote. Never concatenate strings to build SQL commands, use parameters

Comment: What do you mean by "Access does not support multiple users updating the same database"? Access certainly does support multiple users. Each user runs their own copy of GUI frontend which connects to data backend. At least I have no problem with Access frontend and VBA coding and backend on server. However, I have never used C#/.net to code a frontend nor SharePoint to house backend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694921/ms-access-mdb-concurrency

Comment: Maintaining multiple same-structure dbs is a nightmare. Is there ever a need for this data to be merged for reporting? And Excel as a GUI, yuck!

Comment: @jdweng, thank you, I just checked for all users and the environmental variables are set correctly.

Comment: @Steve, Thank you for the side note will update the SQL. Regarding the direct call to the Environment, I just tried but error persists.

Comment: @June7, At the company I work, we are not using a server to maintain the Access files, that´s why we store the actual copies on a SharePoint folder. In the past with other app (VB or C#) when two users at the same time open and update a table, a second access file will be created at the same repo.

Comment: Can you open the mdb file with access?  The database may not be the same version as access as the version 12 in the connection string.  The version in the connection string should match the version of access that save the file.

Comment: @jdweng, Yes, file is the same extension as stated on the query string. Already tried .accdb extension and connector.

Comment: I did not say extension.  The Access database and version of Access has to be the same.  You could have an accdb that was generated with Access 2012 and you machine has 2016 installed.  The database would then need updating or changing the version of ACE in your connection string.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, I had the time last week to investigate the ACE and the Access version and we determined that the ACE and Version are the correct ones. I also double check other modules in the app that uses a connection to the access db and it works perfeclty on all user´s laptops (Read query)

Comment: How long is the pathname when you install?  When install are you using a mapped drive or a network drive name stating with two backslashes?

Comment: Thank you all for the support. I request the IT team to reestablish the MS Access version on those machines, now my code work perfectly without modifications.